# Losing my workspaces after reboot

Tags: raspbian

After creating several new desktops (workspaces), I lose them when I reboot the system.

How can I save them?

I'm running Raspbian.

Answer (score 1):

That is default behavior.

When you reboot, the system resets itself into the state determined by the startup files.

If you need to preserve your desktop then don't reboot.

I've searched for a way to save them and cannot find the solution you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Workspaces are handled by the windows manager, on the Pi OS that's `openbox`. Its default configuration is stored in `/etc/xdg/openbox/lxde-pi-rc.xml`. Edit the `<desktops>` section to create a set of workspaces on startup, for instance:

```
<desktops>
  <number>4</number>
  <firstdesk>1</firstdesk>
  <popupTime>1000</popupTime>
  <names>
    <name>work</name>
    <name>play</name>
    <name>code</name>
    <name>browse</name>
  </names>
</desktops>
```